# Select multiple rows with different criteria for each

Tags: postgresql, select, union

I am trying to put together a query will return sales information across multiple date ranges. I was planning to do something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS thirty_day_sales FROM "MySchema"."MyTable" MT
WHERE MT.date > now()::date - interval '30 days'
UNION
SELECT count(*) AS sixty_day_sales FROM "MySchema"."MyTable" MT
WHERE MT.date > now()::date - interval '60 days'
UNION
SELECT count(*) AS ninety_day_sales FROM "MySchema"."MyTable" MT
WHERE MT.date > now()::date - interval '90 days'
```

Is there another, more efficient way to do this that doesn't use `UNION`? I'd prefer not to have to repeat the `SELECT` and `WHERE` lines over and over, as the actual criteria are a lot longer and move convoluted than this, with multiple tables joined together.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer without more details.

Comment: You may need to de-simplify this a little bit at least - the involvement of other tables could affect the ultimate answer.

Comment: One way to make it more efficient would be to use `UNION ALL` to avoid extra sorts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the data pivoted. It may or may not be faster.

```
SELECT
  count(*) AS '90 days',
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE mt.date > now()::date - interval '60 days')
    AS '60 days'
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE mt.date > now()::date - interval '30 days')
    AS '30 days'
FROM "MySchema"."MyTable" AS mt
WHERE mt.date > now()::date - interval '90 days';
```

Comment: I thought of this, but I'm getting multiple columns too, some of which are based on the joins to other tables and subqueries. My example was just the most trimmed down version of the main query. I don't think pivoted data will work for what we need, but I may try building it out and see what happens.

Comment: Because the query was more complex, the `CROSS JOIN` didn't work, as it was giving me too many combinations. Once I finished writing my original query with `UNION`, it became clearer how to use the technique. It did change the format of the data from a 5x4 grid (one column had time periods) to a single row of 16 columns. But I used meaningful column names and that makes it possible to get the values. And because of the ultimate size of the original query, with many selects and sub-queries, I believe this will end up being faster. It's definitely much small in overall size.

Answer (score 3):

If the count results need to be returned in one column, here is one way to do that avoiding unions.

First, label each row with a value representing the bucket in which the date falls (30 for the bucket of 0 to 30 days, 60 for 30 to 60, and 90 for 60 to 90):

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  "MySchema"."MyTable" AS mt
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN mt.date > now()::date - interval '30 days' THEN 30
        WHEN mt.date > now()::date - interval '60 days' THEN 60
        ELSE                                                 90
      END
  ) AS x (PeriodLength)
WHERE
  mt.date > now()::date - interval '90 days'
;
```

The above will give you a dataset like this:

```
some columns  PeriodLength
------------  ------------
some values   90
...           90
...           ...
...           60
...           60
...           ...
...           30
...           30
...           ...
```

You can now group by `PeriodLength` and count the rows in each group:

```
SELECT
  x.PeriodLength,
  COUNT(*) AS BucketCount
FROM
  "MySchema"."MyTable" AS mt
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN mt.date > now()::date - interval '30 days' THEN 30
        WHEN mt.date > now()::date - interval '60 days' THEN 60
        ELSE                                                 90
      END
  ) AS x (PeriodLength)
WHERE
  mt.date > now()::date - interval '90 days'
GROUP BY
  x.PeriodLength
;
```

That will give you an output like this (showing arbitrary numbers for the sake of an example):

```
PeriodLength  BucketCount
------------  -----------
90            45
60            30
30            35
```

But the results will be for buckets while you want the counts for periods starting from now. The final step, therefore, should be getting the running total of the counts in the ascending order of `PeriodLength`, like this:

```
SELECT
  x.PeriodLength,
  SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY x.PeriodLength ASC) AS BucketCount
FROM
  "MySchema"."MyTable" AS mt
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN mt.date > now()::date - interval '30 days' THEN 30
        WHEN mt.date > now()::date - interval '60 days' THEN 60
        ELSE                                                 90
      END
  ) AS x (PeriodLength)
WHERE
  mt.date > now()::date - interval '90 days'
GROUP BY
  x.PeriodLength
;
```

Now the results will look like this (basing them on the previous output):

```
PeriodLength  BucketCount
------------  -----------
90            110
60            65
30            35
```

The rows may be returned in a different order if you omit an ORDER BY on the SELECT statement itself but the numbers will still match the respective period lengths.

If you prefer proper labels, like `90 days` instead of just `90`, you can further format the output of `PeriodLength`, for instance like this:

```
SELECT
  x.PeriodLength || ' days' AS PeriodLength,
...
```

I would only like to recommend that you do that for the output only rather than in the CASE expression calculating `x.PeriodLength`. Keep the CASE results numeric so that you can use them for sorting, and format them at as high a level as possible (preferably in the client, but if you must do it in SQL, let it be the topmost level).